# R & dplyr: Assigning group-level characteristics to selected group members

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, summary

I have a large data set divided into many small groups by a grouping variable = `grp`; all members of a group are contiguous in the order of the larger data set. The members of a group each have an id code (= `id`) and are numbered sequentially from 1. Within a group, some members meet a logical criterion = `is_child`. Each member has a variable (`momloc`) that contains either zero or the ID number of another of another group member (the mother if present).

I wish to assign to each individual in the data set the number of group members who has momloc equal to their ID, and zero if none do. I am trying to do this in dplyr as I have the groups set up there, and I have code that works, but it is a Rube Goldberg contraption of nested ifelse functions that adds two additional columns for intermediate values, one of which contains a vector, goes through the data set three times, and is incredibly slow. There has to be a better way than that. I'm getting tangled in the different syntax for mutate, working on rows, and summary, working on groups.

Below is a simplified data set and desired outcome

```
grp      <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
id       <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
is_child <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
momloc   <- c(0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2)
data <- tibble(grp, id, is_child, momloc)
```

desired output:

```
out = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the logic behind `out`. Could you please explain why `out[2] = 2` and `out[7] = 1`? Also I don't see where `is_child` comes in.

Comment: Nevermind. It's clear from @akrun's answer;-)

Comment: @MauritsEvers  I think I missed the `1` there.  @andrewH  It is better to show the code that create the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a solution only using `dplyr`.

First, I only keep children (assuming that you only want to count them as your `out[6] = 2` instead of 3). Then, I create a frequency table of `momloc` using `count()`, and merge this to the original data.

```
data %>%
    filter(is_child == 1) %>% # only count for children
    group_by(grp) %>%
    count(momloc) %>%
    right_join(data, by = c("grp" = "grp", "momloc" = "id")) %>%
    rename(
        id = momloc,
        momloc = momloc.y,
        out = n
    ) %>%
    mutate(out = ifelse(is.na(out), 0, out))

#> # A tibble: 11 x 5
#> # Groups:   grp [2]
#>      grp    id   out is_child momloc
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     0        0      0
#>  2     1     2     2        0      0
#>  3     1     3     0        1      2
#>  4     1     4     0        1      2
#>  5     2     1     0        0      0
#>  6     2     2     2        0      0
#>  7     2     3     1        0      0
#>  8     2     4     0        1      3
#>  9     2     5     0        1      2
#> 10     2     6     0        1      2
#> 11     2     7     0        0      2
```

Comment: Man! When I get multiple terrific answers like this, it really hurs to be unable to accept all of them. I learned something new from each of these. I am going to acceept David's answer because I think it is closest to what I literally asked for, and because I am worried about splitting and rbinding  ~9 million households. But I think I will actually try all three, and see which is fastest, probably some time next week. I'll post the result here when I do.

Answer (score 1):

It could easily be the case that I misunderstood your question. But I think a `table()` of `momloc` and `grp` is what you are looking for:

```r
library(tidyverse)
grp      <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) %>% factor
id       <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) %>% factor
is_child <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
momloc   <- c(0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2)
data <- tibble(grp, id, is_child, momloc)

out = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)

data2 <- filter(data, is_child == 1)

data3 <- table(id = factor(data2$momloc, levels = levels(id)), grp = data2$grp) %>% 
    as.data.frame(responseName = "out")

left_join(data, data3, by = c("grp", "id"))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 5
#>    grp   id    is_child momloc   out
#>    <fct> <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#>  1 1     1           0.     0.     0
#>  2 1     2           0.     0.     2
#>  3 1     3           1.     2.     0
#>  4 1     4           1.     2.     0
#>  5 2     1           0.     0.     0
#>  6 2     2           0.     0.     2
#>  7 2     3           0.     0.     1
#>  8 2     4           1.     3.     0
#>  9 2     5           1.     2.     0
#> 10 2     6           1.     2.     0
#> 11 2     7           0.     2.     0

all(cbind(data, out) == left_join(data, data3, by = c("grp", "id")))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Note that I changed `grp` and `id` to factor in lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`.

```
data.moms <- data %>% 
  split(grp) %>%
  lapply(., function(data.grp) {
    data.grp %>% group_by(id, grp) %>% summarise(NumChildren = sum(.$momloc == id))
  }) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
```

We first split the dataframe into multiple dataframes, one for every group, using `split(grp)`.

Then, we use `lapply()` to apply an operation to every data.frame in the list.
For each of these dataframes, we group by `id` and `grp` - even though this means unique 'groups'. We can also group only on `id`, but grouping on both means we get to keep both columns.

Now each data.frame in the list contains 3 columns

- id
- grp
- NumChildren

Now, we can re-combine the summarized dataframes by using `do.call(rbind, .)`.

```
> data.moms
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   id [7]
      id   grp NumChildren
   <dbl> <dbl>       <int>
 1  1.00  1.00           0
 2  2.00  1.00           2
 3  3.00  1.00           0
 4  4.00  1.00           0
 5  1.00  2.00           0
 6  2.00  2.00           3
 7  3.00  2.00           1
 8  4.00  2.00           0
 9  5.00  2.00           0
10  6.00  2.00           0
11  7.00  2.00           0
```